# How to detect topic does not exist within Spring when using @KafkaListener

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

When trying to subscribe to non-existing topic with @KafkaListener, it logs a warning:

```
2021-04-22 13:03:56.710  WARN 20188 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-gg-2, groupId=gg] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 174 : {not_exist=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

How to detect and handle this? I tried errorHandler, it isn't got called:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "not_exist", groupId = "gg", errorHandler = "onError")
    public void receive(String m) {
        log.info("Rcd: " + m);
    }

...

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerErrorHandler onError() {
        return new KafkaListenerErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException e) {
                log.error("handleError Error: {} message: {}", e.toString(), message);
                return message;
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer in **org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaListenerErrorHandler.java**

`* @return the return value is ignored unless the annotated method has a {@code @SendTo} annotation.`